# Why does Hashem send Yona to tell non-Jews to do teshuva?

Tags: gentiles, repentance-teshuvah, yonah-jonah-book-of, nevua-prophecy

Sefer Yona 1:2 Why does Hashem send Yona to tell non-Jews to do teshuva (repentance)? I don't believe this was ever done before or since.

Comment: Didn't G-d send Moshe to Pharaoh?

Comment: @Menachem Concerning your edit, I'm assuming the author used the indefinite article to mean "a prophet," i.e. why G-d sent a prophet — in this case Yonah — though He never sent a prophet to other non-Jews, even not counting Yonah.

Comment: @ba: that makes sense,

Comment: Perhaps this was done before, but is irrelevant to Jewish learning.  The exception being Yonah's story which contains ideas that are relevant to us.

Answer (score 7):

http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=47079&st=&pgnum=567

When Nimrod started doing Avoda Zara, the nation of Ashur had no interest in idolatry. The nation of Ashur left their homes and established a new city "Ninve". In that merit Hashem sent Yona to Ninve to tell them to do Teshuva. (Imrei Chein)

Comment: Can you explain more. Avoda zara means idolatry right. So Ninve is special because it used to be monotheistic?